# Multiple Sliding drawers in a listview

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a listview, for each list item i have unique drawer. So my question is

1.how to achieve opening of single drawer (onclick of handle) at a time resulting into other drawers to be closed if opened.

2.how to decrease the space/gap in both portrait/landscape between the handle and its content container.

Help Appreciated.

Comment: and the sliding drawer is an overlay on each list item and gets opened from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a listview, for each list item i have unique drawer.

I will be stunned if that works properly.

> 1.how to achieve opening of single drawer (onclick of handle) at a time resulting into other drawers to be closed if opened.

Call `close()` on the other drawers.

> 2.how to decrease the space/gap in both portrait/landscape between the handle and its content container.

Try adding some margin to the appropriate side (e.g., `android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"`).

Comment: close() will work but how will i know which drawers handle to be closed.

Comment: Extend SlidingDrawer, add a static list to keep track of instances, then register to listen to OnDrawerOpen and loop through the list closing any other drawers. You also have to figure out some way to remove them from the list when they go away. Though, I think this whole thing has bad idea written all over it.

Comment: @nEx.Software do you have some better/alternative approach to achive this type of behavior. If SlidingDrawer is too expensive in performance. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I would use a ContextMenu, or a dialog triggered from onItemClick().

Comment: @Jitesh: The problem is that you have not bothered to explain what is "this type of behavior".

Comment: @CommonsWare "this type of behavior" i meant i have a sliding drawer for each ListView 'item' as an overlay on top of each list item. Let's say i have 20 items in a list and when i click on a drawer handle (opens left to right) for that particular item, the content container of the sliding drawer will slide out as an overlay on top of that list item. Now here i want to keep track of the drawer handle for each item so that drawer gets closed whenever other drawer is clicked to get open, means only one drawer will be open for an item.

Comment: any suggestions guys on the above comment so far...?